# Bios can't count/determine/identify new RAM

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, bios

Trying to upgrade my desktop's RAM, I've faced a problem I can't solve or diagnose completely, any help much appreciated.

#### Current Hardware

- **Model** - HP 8100 Elite CMT;
- **Motherboard** - HP 304bh (as detected by cmd `wmic baseboard get product,Manufacturer`), [Tech Guide](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02034672), Max RAM claimed supported - 16GB. *Black* DIMM slots are specified as 1st channel (main);
- **RAM** - 8GB as of 4*2GB Samsung M378B5773CH0-CH9 (1333MHz 9-9-9 1.5V unbuffered non-ECC single-sided) installed in *black* DIMM slots.
- [Current BIOS summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrfAJ.jpg)

#### New RAM

2*4GB HyperX Fury HX313C9FR/4 (1333MHz 9-9-9 1.5V unbuffered non-ECC single-sided), packaged separately in plastic cases without any special anti-static bags.

#### Course

0. At first, I've updated BIOS to the last available version from my PC Model's HP support page. It's of 2011 year now.
1. With PC shut down, power unplugged, and motherboard discharged (mobo LED gone off), I've cleared CMOS (via button on mobo), removed 2 *old* RAM planks from *white* slots and installed *new* RAM planks there. On boot, PC beeped once and BIOS started a RAM count. 12000+ Megabytes of RAM was an expected number, but PC shut off upon reaching about 9000+ MB.
2. I left one *white* slot occupied by a *new* plank in PC, supposing the other to be damaged or smth. Result was almost the same, but PC went off at about 6000+ MB.
3. Over next few steps I've tried various combinations of *new* planks and *white* slots with same results - PC shutting down at 9000+ or 6000+ MB count instead of further booting after 12000+ and 8000+ correspondingly.
4. I've removed all *old* planks and installed only *new* planks into *black* slots. As result, I've got a single beep and a black screen with no POST messages at all.

#### Question

What can be done further to make my PC accept these new RAM planks, or are they both somehow inoperable/damaged?

Comment: What about using HP certified memory modules?

Comment: test the new one if they work at all if you only install one new DIMM and all other slots empty. If this does not work you would assume that the new modules are defect.

Comment: sounds like the new ram is incompatible with that motherboard.

Comment: @John, I believe it'll be quite a challenge in Russia. And pricing might be inadequate due to HP logo on it.

Comment: @Robert, none of new planks works in either of black slots. How can they both be defect?...

Comment: @Moab, how are you sure? Specs are identical..

Comment: Either it is defective or incompatible.

Comment: @Moab, seems so. But which one? I mean, these options are absolutely different. Just an "incompatible" suggestion is some mumbo-jumbo to me, not a detailed technical answer I was hoping to get here (instead of Reddit or other non-tech sites). How can RAM of identical specs be "incompatible" ?

Comment: Its a comment not an answer, just move on and buy guaranteed compatible ram from crucial or kingston.

Comment: @Moab, fine, thanks, I guess.. I can move on, but how do I find out which exact RAM modules are guaranteed to be compatible? Furthermore, I'm not sure so popular Crucial is present on Russian market..